# How to monitor the progress of FTP transfer through perl code?

Tags: perl, ftp

We have written an utility to automate file transfer through FTP service using Perl. We want to know how we can track the progress of upload?

Comment: Is this for web, command-line or gui on linux/windows ?

Comment: This is a command-line utility

Answer (score 2):

[Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::FTP) has a `hash` method which will print a `#` mark for every chunk (of a user-definable size) transferred to a user-specified file handle.

You can also enable this progress indicator in the constructor:

> `Hash` - If given a reference to a file handle (e.g., `\*STDERR`), print hash marks (`#`) on that filehandle every 1024 bytes. This simply invokes the `hash()` method for you, so that hash marks are displayed for all transfers. You can, of course, call `hash()`  explicitly whenever you'd like.

I have not used it, but sounds promising.

Comment: @Joy Please explain what you mean by "Anything in Python?"