# FTP with Progressbar

Tags: perl

I need to upload files/folders using "Net::FTP::Recursive" method as rput, i want to know the status of the uploaded files/folders percentage like progressbar.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP::Recursive;

my $ftp_con=Net::FTP::Recursive->new('host.name');
$ftp_con->login('username','password');
$ftp_con->rput('c:\my\test','\root\my\test');

$ftp_con->quit;
```

In the above code I am unable to watch the processes like what are the files are uploading, and what are the files are not uploading and counts of the both.

Please share your suggestions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify the upload status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483802/identify-the-upload-status)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but you may also wish to look at [How to monitor the progress of FTP transfer through perl code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185544/how-to-monitor-the-progress-of-ftp-transfer-through-perl-code)